# How to store system app's settings on /system partition?

Tags: rooting, root-access, system

I have a system app, and I need that both the application itself and its settings shall be in `/system` partition.

I can change the application to be in system by moving from `/data/app` to `/system/app`.

Yet, I see that the configuration/settings are still saved somewhere in `/data` (not sure where).

Is it possible to change it to be in `/system`? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: The system partition is read-only. Therefore you can't place the app data directory there (or better it does not make sense). As the Android system has been developed to work without root access it does not matter that you have root access.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Configurations / settings / cache / databases of every app (system or user) are stored on `/data` or in `/sdcard/Android/` for some apps. That's why `/system` partition is of limited size as compared to `/data`. Android works that way. Apps aren't built to read and write settings to `/system` partition as it holds a read-only filesystem, only changed during OTA updates. A read-write `/system` partition won't fit into [Verified Boot](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/)  mechanism implemented by Android for security and to prevent malware attacks.

**Further reading:** [Android Partitions and Filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565)